# Need help with remove_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to remove the unsightly embedded `<STYLE>` tag the built-in Recent Comments widget puts in my `<HEAD>`, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. It originally calls

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array(&$this, 'recent_comments_style') );
```

to add it (in [wp-includes/default-widgets.php, line 609](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.8.3/wp-includes/default-widgets.php?rev=11770#L609)), and I'm trying to undo it.

I think it should be something like this:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'WP_Widget_Recent_Comments::recent_comments_style');
```

but with all the variations I've tried I still can't get it right. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

#### Possibly Helpful:

- [Function Reference: `remove_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Comment: The second argument for `add_action` / `remove_action` uses `call_user_func_array` syntax, so maybe that knowledge will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_widget_action', 1);
function remove_widget_action() {
    global $wp_widget_factory;

    remove_action( 'wp_head', array($wp_widget_factory->widgets['WP_Widget_Recent_Comments'], 'recent_comments_style') );
}
```

However, it doesn't work because of [this bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10535).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I figured it'd be something like that, but I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. I suppose I can live with it until 2.9 gets released.

Answer (score 1):

```
remove_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'recent_comments_style'));
```

This should work because Wordpress uses the same functions to create the unique IDs whether you remove or add it.

Comment: The problem with this is when add_action was originally called (in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`), it was in the context of the `WP_Widget_Recent_Comments` class, so `$this` in my theme's `functions.php` file means something else.

Comment: Then you need to pass it the variable that the instance of the class is in.

Comment: I've even tried adding `remove_all_actions("wp_head")` in my `functions.php` and I still see the STYLE tag, so maybe it's getting called earlier? How can I find out?

I just want this gone… why are they making this so difficult?

Comment: If you need a quick solution, you can just not call `wp_head()`. But I'm searching around for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove old recentcomments inline style

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_remove_recent_comments_style' );
function my_remove_recent_comments_style() {
    global $wp_widget_factory;
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $wp_widget_factory->widgets['WP_Widget_Recent_Comments'], 'recent_comments_style'  ) );
}
```

tested. works

Answer (score 0):

Now simply:

```
// Remove Recent Comments Default Style
add_filter( 'show_recent_comments_widget_style', '__return_false' ); // Temp hack #14876
```