# How to stop or remove an action being called inside a function of an extended class

Tags: php, wordpress

### The Problem

I am trying to remove an JSON+LD block being added by a WordPress plugin called The Events Calendar.

I believe it is being added by the function called: `Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event` within which the function named `google_data_markup` is responsible for the actual markup which I am trying to stop/prevent from being added to the HTML.

### The Code

From my limited understanding of this, I need to remove this action:

> `add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'google_data_markup' ) );`.

I believe it is being called here, in Single_Event.php:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event' ) ) {
    /**
     * Single event template class
     */
    class Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event extends Tribe__Events__Template_Factory {

        protected $body_class = 'events-single';

        public function hooks() {
            parent::hooks();

            // google data markup
            add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'google_data_markup' ) );

        }

        public function google_data_markup() {
            $event_markup = new Tribe__Events__Google_Data_Markup__Event();
            $html = apply_filters( 'tribe_google_data_markup_json', $event_markup->script_block() );
            echo $html;
        }

        /**
        ...
```

---

### What I've tried

#### Initial Attempts

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356365/need-help-removing-action-from-plugin-file) on StackOverflow, and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96300/removing-an-action-from-an-external-plugin-class) on WordPress Dev Exchange, I tried:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event', 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

and

```
global $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event;
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

But it did not work.

#### Subsequent Attempts

After getting even more desperate and seeing [this slim thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924427/how-to-remove-an-action-added-through-a-class) (the example in that thread seems very similar to mine but no answer provided that I understand), and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/remove-an-action-from-an-external-class), I've also tried this, with the `&` before the variable name (why?):

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( &$Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
```

I've also tried this:

```
function remove_the_events_calendar_jsonld() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ) );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_the_events_calendar_jsonld', 1 );
```

as well as:

```
remove_action( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event', 'google_data_markup' );
```

Please help.  At this point I have no idea if I am making a simple syntax or logic error of sorts, or if I am completely confused and oblivious to how functions, classes and actions work.

### UPDATE 1

As suggested by [Andrew Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431069/4206306) I've tried:

```
global $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event;
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event, 'google_data_markup' ), 20 );
```

and

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( 'Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event', 'google_data_markup' ), 20 );
```

But it still adds the `ld+json` block.

### UPDATE 2 -- Solution

This works:

```
add_filter( 'tribe_google_data_markup_json', '__return_empty_string', 20 );
```

Thank you to [Andrew Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611407/andrew-khan) for the answer.  His explanation is [here, below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431069/4206306).

Comment: The `&` means you are then passing by reference, which means the remove_action function will then access the existing variable, rather than a cloned version of it.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above does not seem to work, but here's a solution that does.

```
add_filter( 'tribe_google_data_markup_json', '__return_empty_string', 20 );
```

For all those wondering, look at the function that the action was calling - it simply echos a HTML string which has a filter applied. That particular filter is also not encapsulated in a class, so it can be accessed easily anywhere. I imagine the one you were using was not designed to be changed by anything but the plugin.

Comment: Much appreciated.  I tried both the version with the global and without but it still unfortunately adds the ld+json.

Comment: Try running 

`global $wp_filter;
print_r($wp_filter);` and see if you can find the action registered there. It might give you a better idea on how to reference it.

Comment: First time trying this -- a massive amount of array data is populated.  I tried searching for `google_data_markup` and `Tribe__Events__Template__Single_Event` but I get nothing :/ Does that mean I am trying to stop the wrong action?

Comment: Not sure, but I'll submit an answer that should work.

Comment: There are 12 `Tribe__Events__Templates` references though, but I have no idea how to read them to glean any insight.

Comment: Will try that right now, also and especially if it doesn't work, I've made a pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/T0qMMX7A).  brb

Comment: It works!  May I ask, how did you figure out that you need to empty out that variable?

Comment: Added an explanation to the answer.